# Rails No association found for name with React Nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

after setup a simple association mas_one through with rails, i've tried to nest the form with react, but in the logs rails shows this message:

> ArgumentError (No association found for name `location'. Has it been
>   defined yet?):
>        app/models/post.rb:17:in`'  app/models/post.rb:3:in `'

the model post has one location through locatable

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, touch: true


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
  has_one :locatable
  has_one :location, through: :locatable

end
```

and in the post controller

```
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :user_id,

                                 location_attributes: [:address])
  end
```

what i've tried to is instead of  **accepts_nested_attributes_for :location** use **:locatable**
and on post_params use **locatable_attributes** instead of location

on post.jsx

i use

```
 buildFormData() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("post[title]", this.state.post.title);
    formData.append("post[body]", this.state.post.body);
    formData.append("post[location_attributes][address]", this.state.address);
}
```

on render

```
render() {
    return ( 
<div className="form-group">
            <label>Address</label>

            <input
              type="text"
              name="location[]"
              onChange={e => this.handleAddressChange(e)}
            />

            {this.renderAddressInlineError}
          </div>)
}
```

and finally the function

```
 handleAddressChange(e) {
    let { address } = this.state;
    address = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ address: address });
  }
```

So, i've tried to change location to locatable and the same error is spitted by the log.

So the question is: is that a react.js issue or the rails model issue?

Answer (score 0):

For someone that has passing through this issue

just use: **`accepts_nested_attributes_for`**

below `**has_one/has_many**`
**`has_one/has_many through`**